# Confusion in macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

The following code works fine

```
#define open {
#define close }
#include<stdio.h>
#define int char

 main()
 open
 int a ;
 printf("This is testing code" );
 close
```

But If I exchange the lines

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define int char
```

as

```
#define int char 
#include<stdio.h>
```

it throws lot of errors like this

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:36,
                 from print.c:19:
/usr/include/bits/types.h:35: error: both 'short' and 'char' in declaration specifiers
/usr/include/bits/types.h:37: error: both 'long' and 'char' in declaration specifiers
/usr/include/bits/types.h:42: error: both 'short' and 'char' in declaration specifiers
/usr/include/bits/types.h:43: error: both 'short' and 'char' in declaration specifiers
.................................................
so and so
```

Actually what is happening inside stdio.h ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be #include<stdio.h>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for failure is that, `#include<stdio.h>` is replaced with the contents of `stdio.h` and when you replace `int` with `char` within the content, you break some declarations.

From `/usr/include/bits/types.h` which gets included indirectly through `stdio.h`

```
.
.
typedef unsigned short int __u_short;
.
.
```

Clearly when you replace `int` with `char` it becomes:

```
typedef unsigned short char __u_short;
```

Which causes compilation error as `short` cannot be applied to the `char` data type.

Answer (score 8):

There are defined variables of type `short int`, `long int` and so on, which obviously fails when you change them through define to `short char` and `long char`.

Redefining basic C types is usually not a good idea.

Comment: I understand perfectly , I saw the changes after $cc -E filename.c

Comment: Redefining language tokens through the preprocessor (i.e., the 'open' and 'close' macros) is also a Very Bad Idea, and has been the source of much heartburn for me in the past.  Not to mention that those particular definitions will bite you if you want to use the POSIX 'open' and 'close' functions.

Answer (score 0):

You #define will get activated and will replace all int's inside stdio.h and all the files it includes causing too many confusing errors.

Since, errors are from types.h, it must modifying some stuff like 'short int' to 'short char' etc.